# Named Entity Recognition from personal dictionary in python

Tags: python, parsing, dictionary, named-entity-recognition

I have a large database with a lot of entries (most of them movies) which has only description as information. A description of the entry with ID 1 (for example) may be like:

> 'Forrest Gump is a 1994 American epic romantic-comedy-drama film based
>   on the 1986 novel of the same name by Winston Groom. The film was
>   directed by Robert Zemeckis and stars Tom Hanks, Robin Wright, Gary
>   Sinise, Mykelti Williamson, and Sally Field.'

Now I have also some txt documents that are basically dictionaries, and are structured like this:

```
actors.txt

Mickey Mouse
Tom Hanks
...

directors.txt

Donald Duck
Robert Zemeckis
...
```

What I want to do is to analyse the description of every entry and parse named entities from my dictionary. So if the text contain 'Tom Hanks' I want to recognize that the entry with ID 1 has Tom Hanks as actor and so on. An output should be something like that:

```
Actor: Tom Hanks, Actor: Robin Wright, Director: Robert Zemeckis, Distributor: Paramount Pictures.
```

or whatever format easy to manipulate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you got to do is use SOLR, setup a few new fieldtypes(like text_actors) in its schema which are linked to appropriate dictionaries, write the appropriate schema, and then import the database. From what I know, this can help you develop a searchable database from which you can query all the results and populate your own database.